# Python regex - strip out beginning and end and leave middle untouched

Tags: python, regex

I need to strip out (i.e., substitute with nothing) everything in a series of filenames on either side of a numeral in the middle. I can do it in two steps, but I would like to do it in one.

Two steps:

```
filename = "NRC_401653_XL3213456321_NRCE_KR.pdf"

front_gone = re.sub(r'(\w{3})_(\d{6})_', '', filename)

both_gone = re.sub(r'_NRCE_KR.pdf', '', front_gone)
```

This will result in just `XL3213456321` remaining, which is what I need. I would like to do this in one step.

Comment: `"NRC_401653_XL3213456321_NRCE_KR.pdf".split('_')[2]`?

Comment: what's wrong with split?

Comment: or `re.sub(r'^\w{3}_\d{6}_(\w+)_NRCE_KR.pdf', r'\1', filename)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import re
filename = "NRC_401653_XL3213456321_NRCE_KR.pdf"
print re.sub(r"\w{3}_\d+_(\w+)_NRCE_KR\.pdf", r"\1", filename)
```

**Output:**

```
XL3213456321
```

`(\w+)` will extract a matching group (number 1). Then you want to replace the whole string into just the middle code so that's why you just need to pass **\1** as the replacement.

Comment: Does it know that it's the group referred to by \1 because it's in parentheses?

Comment: Exactly, because it's a capturing group.

Comment: I see. So if there are more than one parenthetical groups, they're \2, \3 and so on?

Comment: @MarcAdler You got it! :)

Comment: Those are like capturing groups indexes